# Spring-Shell alias name for Input values

Tags: spring-boot, spring-shell

am new to Spring-Shell. I need to collect input values from CLI with Input-alias name. below code accepting values even without an Input-alias name.

```
@ShellMethod("Get full Name.")
public String fullname(@ShellOption({"-f"})   String firstName, 
        @ShellOption({"-l"}) String lastName ) {
    return firstName + " " + lastName ;
}
```

This is what I expected (-f and -l are mandatory inputs)
shell> fullname -f Nithin -l Malathesh

But, This command also working.
shell> fullname Nithin Malathesh

Here both commands are working. but, I need to do only 1st command has to work. If I run 2nd command -> it has to throw error by saying Input-alias name not found.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Spring Shell 2 currently works.

This may be possible in the future when `by-name` and `positional` parsing of parameters is split into two separate components (that would still be active by default)

Comment: Is it still the same? What was the rationale behind this back then as spring shell 1 worked only by-name and that was ok for many. With the current approach it's really mind bogging to detect the source of user's mistake. Today i spent an hour finding a bug until i noticed username is read '--f' as the first argument of the function which has been assigned by positional lookup